# Allow specific accounts to make extrinsic calls

Tags: extrinsic, pallet-staking, filter

In our case, validators are providing multiple different services and I want to restrict them from un-staking or making unbound calls until they have completed the job.

I can set a BaseCall filter to restrict extrinsic calls but Is there a way to conditionally filter accounts that can make extrinsic calls?

```rust
let is_stake_unbound_call = matches!(call, RuntimeCall::Staking(pallet_staking::Call::unbond { value }));
        
if is_stake_unbound_call {
    let has_job = pallet_job::PendingJob::contains_key(account_id)?;
    // return true if all jobs are completed else false
    
}
```

Other possible Approach:

- Block un-bound call and let job-pallet make unbound (internally calling pallet-staking::unbound).

Is there a better way to handle such cases? Any help or advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In short, use a SignedExtension if there is no configurable origin for a pallet.  See [How does one block specific accounts from calling extrinsics for a substrate pallet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/how-does-one-block-specific-accounts-from-calling-extrinsics-for-a-substrate-pal)